# Admin Login in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How to set email and password to admin login using guards??

If I have to login for the 1st time in admin login portal what email and password is it going to verify with.

I tried adding record to database directly and logging in but that doesn't work.

when i try to login with email and password in the database, i get the following error

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\Admin given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Alumni datatable - Copy (2) - Copy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 434

AdminAuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class AdminAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin(){
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }
 
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
 
        if(auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'),  'password' => $request->input('password')])){
            $user = auth()->guard('admin')->user();
            if($user->is_admin == 1){
                return redirect()->route('adminDashboard')->with('success','You are Logged in sucessfully.');
            }
        }else {
            return back()->with('error','Whoops! invalid email and password.');
        }
    }
 
    public function adminLogout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->guard('admin')->logout();
        Session::flush();
        Session::put('success', 'You are logout sucessfully');
        return redirect(route('adminLogin'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you have to extends Authenticatable in your Admin Model**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{


}
```

Comment: It cleared the error. Thank You.... But how to login to a admin portal, where does it verify email and password on our 1st login